# Lighting and Camera Angle of the Video

Tags: lighting

I'm trying myself with my first video. I made the figures with crayon/colored pencils. I have made the video at night with a desktop light.

- The pencil drawings seem to glow, how can i prevent this? (Some post processing?)
- How is the overall angel of the video? Should it be different?

This is the video:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you are lighting this, but generally speaking photographing flat work requires an even light source. Usually two diffused lights above the surface at 45 degree angles should accomplish this task. Your lighting suggests that you are not using a diffused source(s) as witnessed by the hot spot in the middle of your screen hence the halo effect.

Another thing I noticed is that you are using a camera with auto-exposure mode engaged, subsequently every time you move your hand into the frame the light value shifts. If this is a Point & Shoot camera then there is not much you can do about this, but if it's a DSLR you need to lock down the exposure so it is not changing.

There are three manual controls that generally should be locked down before recording:
1) white balance,
2) focus,
3) exposure,

Many Point & Shoot cameras will allow you to set the white balance and focus, but not exposure.

If you are in this situation, then the only way to defeat the exposure changes would be to keep the light even through out the frame and sequence. For instance if you were wearing white gloves this would help keep the auto exposure from going lighter to capture your skin tone, or if you changed the back ground, and made it the same value as your hands--awkward yes, but even light would likely improve the entire scene.

Hope this helps

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! I didn't notice the exposure & etc things. This is a iPhone 4 and my only option :)
I will however, look what i can do. Thank you very much for this invaluable information!

Comment: You are very welcome. I've updated my answer to address the light source too.

Comment: I've downloaded a Camera app which will promise to keep focus and exposure steady. Let's say how it will work out :)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use at least one more light source! From the bottom of the image (good luck with that) to avoid the shade of your fingers and paper not flat to the surface. I would also use a warmer light color but that's a preference. I think the angle of the shot is fine. Use bigger pieces of paper so it's easier for you to work with (specially if you set the lighting fixture between you and the table). Please read the faq and find out why you got a down vote on this post (it wasn't me!). I don't think the edges are 'glowing' and I'm not a video guy but to solve that issue I would say that the amount of light is too much. Experiment by dimming the light source down and also with the lens shutter to deny some light to go through. Don't try to fix it afterwords! Good luck!